# css file missing after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cakephp

I created a form to send text. I redirected the page after form submission with different controller and action. Whenever I submit a form, the css file "temp.css" which I am using is missing for that particular page alone. So that I am getting some design issues. Can anyone explain why this happens.

**TEXT**

```
<div  ng-init='textcontents = <?php  echo (!empty($text_info))?json_encode($text_info):'[{"0":"empty"}]'; ?>'> 
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('TwilioText', array('url' => array('controller' =>'Emailer','action' => 'text_sendmsg'),'novalidate')); ?>
    <div class="hidden">
    <?php
        $value = isset($cust_detail['customerid']) ? $cust_detail['customerid'] : '';
        echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.customerid', array('type' => 'text', 'ng-model' => 'livedata.customerid', 'value' => $value));
        echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.firstname', array('type' => 'text', 'ng-model' => 'livedata.firstname', 'value' => $cust_detail['firstname']));
        echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.lastname', array('type' => 'text', 'ng-model' => 'livedata.lastname', 'value' => $cust_detail['lastname']));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="textmsg">
        <div class="textleft pull-left">
            <?php foreach ($textChat as $key => $value) {
                    if($value['msg'] == 'in'){ ?>
                        <div class="time2"> <p> <?php echo $value['formatedtime'];?> </p> </div> 
                        <div class="inbox">  <p> <?php echo $value['sent_msg'];?> </p> </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="time"> <p> <?php echo $value['formatedtime'];?> </p> </div>
                        <div class="outbox"> <p> <?php echo $value['sent_msg'];?> </p> </div>
                    <?php }
                  } ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="textright pull-right">
            <div class="righttop pull-left">
                <div class="righttop_left pull-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php
                        $value = isset($cust_detail['phone1']) ? $cust_detail['phone1'] : '';
                        echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.msgSentNmbr', array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                                                                    'placeholder' => 'Phone', 
                                                                                    'label' => false, 
                                                                                    'class' => 'form-control', 
                                                                                    'div' => false, 
                                                                                    'value' => $value));
                        echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.msgTitle', array('label' => false, 
                                                                                 'class' => 'text-list', 'div' => false,
                                                                                 'type' => 'select',
                                                                                 'ng-options' => "key as value.textName for (key , value) in textcontents",
                                                                                 'ng-change' => "textcontent = textcontents[textName].textDescription;",
                                                                                 'ng-model' => "textName",
                                                                                 'empty' => 'Content')); ?>
                    </div>

                        <?php 
                        $hostname            = "www." . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. ".com";
                        $CRMuser             = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                        $trade               = "/trade-in-value-louisville-car-appraisal.php";
                        $schedappt           = "/salesman.php?sales_id=$CRMuser";
                        $creditapplication   = "/car-credit-approval-online-form.php";
                        $directions          = "www.kiastore.com/directions";
                        $fname               = '<# sfirstname>';
                        $laname              = '<# slastname>';
                        $callme              = '<# sphone>';
                        $emailme             = '<# semail>';
                        $mycontact           = $fname.' '.$laname.'<br>'.$callme.'<br>'.$emailme;
                        ?>
                    <div class="text_btn">
                        <input type="button" value="Trade"          class="btn-img btn-img-pos"  onclick="insertLink('<?php echo $hostname.$trade?>')">
                        <input type="button" value="Credit App"     class="btn-img btn-img-pos2" onclick="insertLink('<?php echo $hostname.$creditapplication?>')">
                        <input type="button" value="Inventory Link" class="btn-img btn-img-pos3" onclick="insertLink('<?php echo $hostname?>')">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="righttop_right pull-left">
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('', array('label' => false, 
                                                          'class' => 'text-list', 
                                                          'div' => false,
                                                          'type' => 'select',
                                                          'empty' => 'Current Deals')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text_btn">                    
                        <input type="button" value="Sched Apt"   class="btn-img btn-img-pos"   onclick="insertLink('<?php echo $hostname.$schedappt ?>')">
                        <input type="button" value="Directions"  class="btn-img btn-img-pos2"  onclick="insertLink('<?php echo $directions ?>')">
                        <input type="button" value="My Contact"  class="btn-img btn-img-pos3"  onclick="insertLink('<?php echo $mycontact; ?>')" id="text_list">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightbottom pull-left">
                <?php 
                echo $this->Form->textarea('TwilioSentText.sent_msg', array('placeholder' => 'Text Content',
                    'ng-model' => 'textcontent', 'label' => false, 'id' => 'nwtext', 'class' => 'form-control', 'div' => false, 'value' => ''));
                echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.url',array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $url));
                echo $this->Form->submit('Send',array('class' => 'btntext_send',  'id' => 'btntext_send','div' => false,'name'=>'submit'));
                echo $this->Form->submit('Schedule',array('class' => 'btntext_schd','div'=>false,'name'=>'submit'));
                echo $this->Form->end(); 
                ?>            
              </div>
            <span id="btntxt">Or Press Enter</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function text_sendmsg() {
        if ($this->request->data['submit'] == 'Schedule') {
            if (($this->request->is('post'))) {
                $this->autoSendText();
                $this->Session->setFlash('Text to be sent has been scheduled');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Failed');
            }
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Todolist', 'action' => 'index'));
        } elseif (($this->request->data['submit'] == 'Send')) {
            $url = explode('edit/',$this->request->data['TwilioSentText']['url']);
            $rurl = explode('-',$url[1]);
            $cust_id = $rurl[0].'-'.$rurl[1].'-31/formmini';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $send = $this->sendTextMsg();
                if($send == 1)
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Saved Successfully');
                else
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Customer Text disabled');
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Failed to send');
            }
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Customers','action' => 'edit/'.$cust_id));
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any error on form submission? Please enable the error reporting.. and check again

Comment: What adds the css file to the page? DO you see it in the source?

Comment: no i didnt recieve any errors after submission. The form is getting submitted properly and also the values are getting  stored in the database. @nishant.

Comment: I couldnt get you. Can you plz make it clear @ epascarello

Comment: @Surya I think @epascarello is asking how and where you include the CSS. Are you using `$this->Html->css()` in your View template? Perhaps you could add this to your question.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja: yes i have inclued echo $this->Html->css('temp') in the default.ctp file in the layout.

Comment: @Surya when you submit the form and have your CSS issue what does your HTML source code look like? Is the markup for linking the CSS still there or has it completely disappeared? Perhaps the linked CSS file contains CakePHP error messages that prevent it from being included correctly. It would be a good idea to check Cake's error logs after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Check your layout file or like this which includes the css file.

Comment: He can't comment, not enough reputation. We've all been there.

Comment: @Andrew still this can not be considered as an answer.. An answer should contain details explanation of the problem and how to solve it. this is just an one line guess

Comment: Yeah, I can't comment individually :(

Comment: @NishantSolanki Well no, it's not an answer, I was just pointing out the obvious, I guess.

Comment: @Faradox i guess 50 reputation is needed to gain comment  Privilege, still there are many other ways to get reputed.. Best luck

Answer (score 0):

I embedded a form on my website with FormMail script.

In the root folder of my server I have the following structure:

`/index.html`

`/redirect-page.html`

`/css/styles.css`

`/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl`

My index page includes the form with a redirect input:

`<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.my.domain/redirect-page.html"/>`

When I wrote redirect.html I copied and pasted the head from the index page. It contained the link to styles.css as follows:

`<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

The form submission worked properly and I was redirected to redirect.html, however redirect.html was not linking to css/styles.css.

I realized that redirect.html was being loaded from the FormMail.pl file in /cgi-bin, and the link reference was looking for styles.css in that same folder.

So I edited the header of redirect.html to correct the path to my style.css as follows to indicate going out of /cgi-bin and back into /css:

`<link href="./css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

After that, redirect.html was linking to styles.css.